# Setup Proxy to invoke web service's methods

Tags: java, web-services, proxy

I have implemented a WS client in Java from an existing WSDL I got.
I can connect, invoke WS methods and everything works great. 
 But....
I am supposed to use a Proxy for communication!!!

Already tried many ways to do that, but nothing works:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("host",Integer.parseInt("8008")));
URL url = new URL(theUrl);
```

`HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
    uc.connect();`

Or i tried

```
System.setPropertry(String, String)
```

So can set `host` and `proxy` and `proxySet`= true.

But according to colleagues this is not what I should do as it sets global properties and it will not work with many individual runs within out System.
Any ideas how I am supposed to do this?
Any help appreciated,
 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used a class to extend `java.net.ProxySelector` let's call it `MyProxySelector.java`
And in the implemented `select()` method, I check the URI, if it is a URI I which to connect through a proxy, that is the Web service's URI then I create a proxy:

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(theHost, thePort);
proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
```

add it to my proxy list:

```
List<Proxy> proxyList = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
proxyList.add(proxy);
```

and return the proxy list.